# How to highlight a newly inserted row in mat-table angular 7

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a mat-table where I display list of rows.
I have a add new button through which user can manually add a row.
Working Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axjzov-8zmcnp
I want the option to highlight the newly inserted row for 2-3 sec so that the user can see the newly created row.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: I see that when you add a new element, it is shown at the top of the list which means it is the first child. So, to the first child, you can add a class called highlighted and remove it after few seconds through a setTimeout

Comment: If you are using jquery, you can use 
$('your first child class').effect("highlight", {}, 3000);

Comment: @dileepkumarjami can you please show me how to do it.No i am not using jQuery I am using typescript and angular

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add this to the style css

```
    mat-row.mat-row {
        animation: highlight 3s;
    }

    @keyframes highlight {
      0% {
        background: red
      }
      100% {
        background: none;
      }
    }
```

In case you only want to highlight the new rows, you need to define the new row to add a class to them.

So let's say the class name is "highlight".

In the component you add:

```
export class TableFilteringExample {
    //...
    newRowIndex = 0;
    //...
    addElement() {
        this.newRowIndex++;
        //...
    }
}
```

In the HTML template file:

```
    <!--...-->

    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let i = index"
        [ngClass]="{'highlight': i < newRowIndex}"></mat-row>

    <!--...-->
```

And in the style file:

```
.highlight {
    animation: highlight 3s;
}

@keyframes highlight {
    0% {
        background: red
    }
    100% {
        background: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: When i load the page all the columns are highlighted ... is it possible to add class or do something that other rows do not get highlighted

Answer (score 0):

In `table-filtering-example.css` I have added the following class

```
.highlight{
  background: green;  
}
```

In `table-filtering-example.ts` I have added the following variable
`selectedRowIndex: number = -1;`
And when `addElement()` gets called in that I have incremented the position value of every row entry of `ELEMENT_DATA` using `filter` operator.

After that I set `selectedRowIndex` variable to 1 and add a time Interval event of 3sec which reset it to -1.

In `table-filtering-example.html` I have edited the following code

```
 <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
     [ngClass]="{'highlight':selectedRowIndex == row.position}"
        ></mat-row>
```

[Here](https://angular-axjzov-rp8ky7.stackblitz.io) is the updated working stackBlitz link.